# Formulate the problem using the given predicates.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

Statement : `If Mr.M is guilty, then no witness is lying unless he is afraid`

Also given in question : There is a witness who is afraid.

Given predicates :

- G−Mr.M
  is guilty
- W(x)−x
  is a witness
- L(x)−x
  is lying
- A(x)−x
  is afraid

Answer according to me is :
`G⟹∀x(¬L(x)⟹¬A(x))`

However according to [this answer site](http://gateoverflow.in/20939/tifr2012-a-2) , the answer is :
\begin{array}{c} G \implies \lnot \exists x: \Bigl (W(x) \land L(x) \land \lnot A(x) \Bigr )\\[1em] \equiv\\[1em] G \implies \forall x: \Biggl (W(x) \implies \Bigl ( \lnot A(x) \implies \lnot L(x) \Bigr ) \Biggr ) \end{array}

If I am wrong, kindly explain where my logic went wrong?

Comment: In your answer you have forgotten the part that $x$ is a witness.

Comment: Try step-by-step "no witness is lying unless he is afraid"; the part: ""no witness is lying" must be: $\lnot \exists x \ (W(x) \land L(x))$ that is equivalent to: $\forall x \ (W(x) \to \lnot L(x))$.

Comment: "Unless" is tricky: can be $\lor$. If so, we can write:  $∀x \ [W(x)→(¬L(x) \lor A(x))]$ that in turn is equivalent to: $∀x \ [W(x)→(¬A(x) \to ¬L(x))]$.

Comment: "Going backward" we have the equivalent: $∀x [¬W(x) \lor A(x) \lor ¬L(x))]$ i.e. $∀x ¬[W(x) \land ¬A(x) \land L(x))]$ i.e $¬∃x \ [W(x) \land ¬A(x) \land L(x))]$.

Comment: It is the unless part that is confusing me,because I studied that p => q can be said as `not p unless q` and if applied to given statement, I think it is in this form.

Comment: My thought process goes on to directly translate the english statement to conditional statement. May be that's where I am wrong? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Correct: $p \to q$ is equiv to $\lnot p \lor q$, i.e. to "not $p$ unless $q$".

Comment: Okay, so from the above I understand that ∀x [W(x)→(¬L(x)∨A(x))] can be written as ∀x [W(x)→(L(x)→A(x))] and then finally use the contrapositive ∀x [W(x)→(¬A(x)→¬L(x))] which is equivalent. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

1. You forgot to say that you are talking about witnesses. So, you need to add a $W(x)$ predicate
2. You need to say that for all witnesses $x$: '$x$ is not lying unless $x$ is afraid', which is equivalent to '$x$ is not lying if $x$ is not afraid' (whenever you see 'unless', just substitute 'of not'!) , which is symbolized as $\neg A(x) \to \neg L(x)$ You have $\neg L(x) \to \neg A(x)$, which is just the other way around

Comment: I have this confusion regarding unless. According to your answer, 'x is not lying unless x is afraid' is in the form q=>p. But according to this article [link](https://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/logic/logic3.html) the statement is in the form 'not p unless q' i.e. p => q.

Comment: @momo Yeah, 'unless' is always tricky! :)  The article is right: 'not $p$ unless $q$' is $ p \to q$.  But I was right too: if you substitite 'if not' for 'unless', you get:    'not $p$ unless q' =  'not $p$ if not  $q$' = $\neg q \to \neg p$ = $p \to q$.  Likewise,  'x is not lying unless x is afraid' =  'x is not lying if not x is afraid' = $\neg A(x) \to \neg L(x)$ = $L(x) \to A(x)$

Comment: oh okay! I understand now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @momo You're welcome. Glad I could help! :)