# Conversion of a given statement into predicate logic?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

> Statement : If Mr. A is guilty, then no witness is lying unless he is afraid. There is a witness who is afraid.

**Hint:** Formulate the problem using the following predicates:

$G$: Mr. A is guilty

$W(x)$: $x$ is a witness

$L(x)$: $x$ is lying

$A(x)$: $x$ is afraid

> Which of the following statements is true?

- Mr.A is guilty.
- Mr.A is not guilty.
- From these facts one cannot conclude that Mr.A is guilty.
- There is a witness who is lying.
- No witness is lying.

---

**My try:**

I formulated the problem as follows:
$$
\neg A(x) \rightarrow \left ( G \rightarrow \neg\exists x \left ( W(x) \wedge L(x) \right )  \right )
$$
Then, I used the Exportation Law and Modus Tollens:
$$
\left ( \neg A(x) \wedge G \right ) \rightarrow \left ( \neg \exists x \left ( W(x) \wedge L(x) \right ) \right )
$$
$$
\exists x\left ( W(x) \wedge L(x) \right )
$$
and I drew the conclusion 
$$
\neg A(x) \rightarrow \neg G
$$
OR
$$G \rightarrow A(x)$$

The same question has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328588/formulate-the-problem-using-the-given-predicates), but I need to confirm my approach for this problem. Is this correct?

Comment: You say "Which of the following statements is true?" but then don't list the actual statements. This question is incomplete.

Comment: @5xum I missed the options. I've edited now.

Comment: @5xum Could you please withdraw the closing request ?

Comment: I did. The question is now complete, so I retracted my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is "If a person is not afraid, then $G$ is guilty" which just intuitively should sound wrong to you.

---

I'd say you have two separate sentences. The first is

> If Mr.A is guilty, then no witness is lying unless he is afraid

And this sentence starts with an "If". Now, "If $X$, then $Y$" sentences translate usually to $A\implies B$, so I suggest you do the same here. This means the logical statement will start with $G\implies$, not with $\neg A\implies$.

Now, the second part must be the "no witness is lying unless he is afraid". This can be rephrased either as

> "if a witness is lying, he is afraid", so $(W(x)\land L(x))\implies A(x)$

or as

> "if a witness is not afraid, he is not lying", so $(W(x)\land \neg A(x)\implies \neg L(x)$

(it's easy to see those two phrases are logically equivalent).

---

So, the resulting statement is

$$G\implies \forall x:((W(x)\land L(x))\implies A(x))$$

with the second statement of course being $\exists x: W(x)\land A(x)$.

---

Now, from jsut the fact that the only statement you have about $G$ is $$G\implies\text{something}$$ it should be clear that there is no way you can prove that $G$ is true (it could always be false, ant that statement will still be true).

However, you **can** maybe prove $\neg G$ since $A\implies B$ is the same as $\neg B$ implies $\neg A$.

In our case, this means we are interested in the statement

$$\neg(\forall x:((W(x)\land L(x))\implies A(x)))\implies \neg G$$

which simplifies to:

$$\exists x: W(x)\land L(x)\land \neg A(x) \implies \neg G$$

which means "if there exists a lying witness that is not afraid, then mr. A is guilty".

---

However, you only know about one witness, and you don't know if they are lying. You know that if they are lying, then mr. A is not guilty, but if they are not lying, mr. A might be guilty or not, you just don't know.

Comment: I made a bit mistake in my conclusion. Can you please check now the new conclusion ?

Comment: @JonGarrick So "if mr. A is guilty, then $x$ is afraid... I don't think this is correct either. Like I already said, I don't even agree with $$
\neg A(x) \rightarrow \left ( G \rightarrow \neg\exists x \left ( W(x) \wedge L(x) \right )  \right )
$$

and even if I did, in your conclusion, what quantifier should be in front? Is this true for all $x$? because it certainly isn't, you could well have $x$ that aren't even witnesses, so anything could be true for those!

Comment: I got my mistake ! Thanks for nice explaination !!

Comment: @JonGarrick You're welcome :)